# Finding fuctional dependencies and candidate keys

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I have number of files, each containing all *reviews* for a specific *hotel* (one file corresponds to one *hotel*, e.g. *hotel_2194.dat*). Each review is of the type:

```
<Author>PERKEISHA
<Content> I had a great time at...
<Date>Mar 8, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>1
<Value>1
<Rooms>1
<Location>5
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>5
<Business service>1
```

I constructed the following relation:

```
Review (Hotel_ID, Author, Content, Date, No. Readers, No. Helpful, Overall, Value, Rooms, Location, Cleanliness, Check in, Service, Business service)
```

However, I am having trouble identifying the functional dependencies and candidate keys. I was thinking of something like `(Hotel_ID, Author, Content, Date)` for a primary key but then I realized that the same `Author` may post the same `Review` (in terms of contents) about the same `Hotel` on the same `Date` and just change his overall mark. Am I thinking too hard about this? I'd be grateful if someone could suggest some functional dependencies and keys.

Answer (score 1):

`Content` looks like a free-form text field - that generally makes it a horrible choice for a primary key column. `Hotel_ID`, `Author`, and `Date` are probably reasonable (especially if `Date` is "date of stay at hotel", rather than "date of posting of review").

I would generally expect that an updated review would replace the original. If you want to retain older version, I would include both "date of stay" and "date of posting" (and both could be part of the key); this would allow the same person to have a review for each stay (as ratings for a stay last month could remain valid, even if a review of a later stay had different ratings).

It would be likely that you would want a Hotel table, and an Author table (to hold information about those entities that wouldn't change from review to review (hotel info, author's account info (assuming some sort of login process).

NOTE: In practice, I would probably want to treat `Hotel_ID`, `Author`, and the two date fields as a functional key (must be unique), but use an auto-incrementing integer as the actual, literal primary key (saves space on indexing and in any tables that might need to reference it, easier to use in queries, etc.)